# How to replace the column content by using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a product information file with more than millions records. The CSV file looks like:

```
    Product    CategoryName    SalesUnit  Other Columns...
      p1           a12             41

      p2           x5              72

      p3           x5              69

      p4           c21             80

      p5           b16             59

      p6           x5              75 
      ..           ..              ..
```

And I have a mapping file(CategoryCode <-> CategoryName) as following. The mapping file has around 200 records:

```
    CategoryCode CategoryName

       1.0            a12

       2.0            b13 
       3.0            b16
       4.0            c12

       5.0            c21

       6.0            x5

       ..             ..
```

Eventually, I want to replace value of CategoryName with CategoryCode:

```
    Product    Category    SalesUnit   Other Colulmns..
     p1          1.0           41

     p2          6.0           72

     p3          6.0           69

     p4          5.0           80

     p5          3.0           59

     p6          6.0           75 
     ..          ..            ..
```

My approach is to use the udf of spark dataframe:

```
    udf { (CategoryName: String) =>
        if (CategoryName.trim() == "a12") 1.0
        else if (CategoryName.trim() == "b13") 2.0
        else if (CategoryName.trim() == "b16") 3.0
        else if (CategoryName.trim() == "c12") 4.0
        else if (CategoryName.trim() == "c21") 5.0
        else if (CategoryName.trim() == "x5") 6.0
        else if (CategoryName.trim() == "z12") 7.0
        else if (...) ...
        ... ...
        else 999.0
    }
```

Any other elegant approach to achieve the replacement without by coding so many if...else clause? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join the mapping file with the csv on trimmed category then select only the fields you need

Comment: Thanks, your approach is better than mine. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can **join both the dataFrame** on the Categoryname and then drop the Categoryname itself as you are not needing it afterwards.

You can do something like this:

```
scala> //Can have more columns , have taken just these columns just to demonstrate

scala> val df1=sc.parallelize(Seq(("p1","a12",41),("p2","x5",72),("p3","x5",69))).toDF("Product","CategoryName","SalesUnit")
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Product: string, CategoryName: string ... 1 more field]

scala> //Category code dataFrame

scala>  val df2=sc.parallelize(Seq((1.0,"a12"),(4.0,"c12"),(5.0,"c21"),(6.0,"x5"))).toDF("CategoryCode","CategoryName")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [CategoryCode: double, CategoryName: string]

scala> val resultDF=df1.join(df2,"CategoryName").withColumnRenamed("CategoryCode","Category").drop("CategoryName")
resultDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Product: string, SalesUnit: int ... 1 more field]

scala> resultDF.show()
+-------+---------+--------+                                                    
|Product|SalesUnit|Category|
+-------+---------+--------+
|     p1|       41|     1.0|
|     p2|       72|     6.0|
|     p3|       69|     6.0|
+-------+---------+--------+
```

**P.S:** This is just a small demonstration.

Comment: Very appreciate your answer. Your demonstration is very helpful to me. I accept Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz's answer as he responded quickly.